# El script sólo se añade en la primer elemento de un forEach

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy queriendo utilizar la librería `dotdotdot`.

Estoy imprimiendo unas descripciones y no quiero que salga todo el mensaje , bueno el primer elemento que imprime lo hace, pero el resto ya no agrega la función de `dotdotdot`.

```
<?php foreach($listadoOfertas as $listadoOfertas){ ?>
        <div class="oferta-empleo">
            <img class ="logo-oferta" src="imagen1.png" alt="">

            <div class="datos-oferta">
                <h2 class="titulo-oferta"><a href=""><?php  echo $listadoOfertas['titulo'];?></a></h2>
                <p id='parrafo-padding'> <strong>Empresa: </strong><?php  echo $listadoOfertas['empresa'];?></p>
                <p ><strong>Localidad: </strong><?php  echo $listadoOfertas['localidad'];?> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<strong>Fecha: 
                </strong><?php  echo $listadoOfertas['fecha_publicacion'];?></p> 

                <div id="descripcion">
                <p><?php  echo $listadoOfertas['descripcion_oferta'];?>
                </p>
                </div> 
                <script> $('#descripcion').dotdotdot();</script>
            </script> 

             </div>                
          </div>       
        <?php };?>
```

Comment: Se debe a que todos los elementos id=descripcion tienen el mismo id y debería ser distinto.

Comment: Muchas gracias Carmen, era eso.

Comment: @Marcos Hola Marcos, si la respuesta fue correcta, pero ya hice lo que me dijiste no?

Comment: @Marcos Pues no sé que raro, le di a lo de respuesta útil, le daré a la de abajo que también es correcta  Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de `id` se puede utilizar una clase común a todos los elementos descripción.

```
<div class="descripcion" id="desc1">
  <p><?php  echo $listadoOfertas['descripcion_oferta'];?></p>
</div>
```

Y en el `script` utilizar la clase para recorrer los elementos:

```
$(".descripcion").each(function() {
    id_des = this.id;
    $("#"+id_des).dotdotdot();
});
```

Debería aplicarse a todos los elementos con la clase 'descripcion';

Comment: En realidad, deberías poder hacer `$(".descripcion").dotdotdot();`